# How do I scroll the page up to show errors on the checkout page of woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, scroll, woocommerce, checkout

On woocommerce checkout page when an order is placed if there are any errors in the form the errors are shown at top.

I want the page to scroll up and focus on errors but the page does not scroll up.

https://dev.clipcertification.com/checkout/

If payment details are not filled an error comes up and the page also scrolls to focus on payment error but not on general form errors.

I checked in console, an error is coming 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined', its due to the validation being used on birthdate field.

I am using following code for Birthdate field validation:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery.validator.addMethod(
    "dateUS",
    function(value, element) {
        var check = false;
        var re = /^\d{1,2}\-\d{1,2}\-\d{4}$/;
        if( re.test(value)){
            var adata = value.split('-');
            var dd = parseInt(adata[0],10); // was gg (giorno / day)
            var mm = parseInt(adata[1],10); // was mm (mese / month)
            var yyyy = parseInt(adata[2],10); // was aaaa (anno / year)
            var xdata = new Date(yyyy,mm-1,dd);
            if ( ( xdata.getFullYear() == yyyy )  && ( xdata.getMonth () == mm - 1 ) && ( xdata.getDate() == dd ) )
                check = true;
            else
               check = false;
        } 
        else 
            check = false;
            return this.optional(element) || check;
    }, 
    "Invalid Date (dd-mm-yyyy)"
);
// attach Validate plugin to form
jQuery("#custom-checkout").validate();

});
```

and jquery.validate.js file.

It does not matter whether I use the above code in header or footer.
Also, form gets submitted even if date validation is false

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: Its standard woocommerce form code, haven't customized.

Comment: I am getting an error in console 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined', it is due to I have added a validation on Birthdate field. And form is also not getting scrolled up, kindly help.

Comment: Could you please edit that into your question. Also, please note in your question that you are using the standard form code, including the fact you're not customizing anything.

Comment: Please help. I have added code.

Comment: Can anyone please have a look on the code and help.

Comment: In firefox I am getting TypeError: validator is undefined